# Windows XP blocking zip files created by my program

Tags: java, windows, zip

I have the following java code to create a zip file. The file works fine on linux but Windows XP's native extractor is blocking it. The workaround recommended (go to file properties and unblock) does not work either. I have read about similar issues on the web and a similar post on stackoverflow about this but none of those solutions work for me. Any ideas on what could be causing the issue.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zipFile = new ZipOutputStream(byteOut);
loop {
    byte [] tempData = "some data".getBytes("UTF-8"); 
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("blah.txt"); //no path here
    entry.setSize(tempData.length); //read somewhere that this might solve the issue, didn't work
    entry.setTime((new Date()).getTime()); //tried with and without this.. this is probably redundent since putNextEntry sets the time to current too.
    zipFile.putNextEntry(entry);  
    zipFile.write(tempData);
    zipFile.closeEntry();
     }
zipFile.close();
```

P.S.

1. I do not have windows defender on my windows machine.
2. I have tried setting the size of the zip entry and it still doesn't work.
3. There is no absolute path specified in the zip entry and there are no slashes in the path.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**: Yes, I have tested on other machines with Windows XP with the same results. I downloaded 7zip but couldn't figure out how to check the compression method. If someone can tell me the steps to do that I can add the compression method to the comments.

**Edit 2**: I use the windows native extraction wizard which says "Windows has blocked access to these files to help protect your computer". Below this message there is a link that says "Windows blocks files that are marked as not trusted. Why were these files blocked and how can I open them". Clicking the link gives you the workaround (file properties -> unblock) that does not work.

Comment: Weird... tested on another machine? Also, what compression method it's used (7-zip can tell you)?

Comment: what do you mean by "block"?  do you mean that it sets the zip as untrusted, or that it errors when unzipping?  If it errors, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the issue, my entry file names had a time stamp in them with a : and windows freaked out over it.

ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("blah.txt");  <- time stamp here, didn't think this was important so didn't copy the real names here.